# Is there a R function similar to resample in python?

Tags: python, r, time-series

when i handling the time series data,i will sampling and frequency convertion of data ,in python ,it is sample in using resample ,how can i do the same thing  in R easily?

```
example:
the raw data:

input:df.head()

output:2016-10-19 07:15:00    12480
        2016-10-19 06:10:00     9134
        2016-10-19 06:05:00     9589
        2016-10-19 06:00:00     9530
        2016-10-19 05:55:00     8453
```

the data is sampled once every 5 minutes.
frequency convertion use resample in python:

```
input:df_sum = df.resample('30min').sum()

output:2016-10-11 07:00:00    21100
       2016-10-11 07:30:00    67388
       2016-10-11 08:00:00    81758
       2016-10-11 08:30:00    84120
       2016-10-11 09:00:00    89987
```

the data is aggregated every 30 mins.
**How can i do the same thing easily in R?**

Comment: `aggregate(df[2], list(cut(df[[1]], '30 mins')), sum)` maybe?

Comment: It is not work,"Error in cut.default(dd[[1]], "30 mins") : 'x'必需为数值"  maybe can't recognize the "30 mins".

Comment: It's the `cut.POSIXt` method, so your datetimes need to be parsed to POSIXct or POSIXlt.